# How do I make the tip of a vortex appear under the rest of the image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, illustrator-effects

I'm trying to replicate this image I found on the internet in Adobe Illustrator CC 2019:

[image: Black and white vortex]

When I made my Vortex by using the **3D Resolve** effect, I couldn't get the tip of it (In the first photo, the tip is behind the center of the image) to appear under the image. Here is the vortex I made:

[image: Vortex with tip issue]

If you look closely, you'll see what I'm talking about. How can I make this appear like the first image, where the tip is under the vortex?

Comment: You could do this in a 3D program like Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view appears to be looking down onto the cone, when the it should be looking up into the cone instead.  Perhaps try to replicate this as shown below. The cone points down, and I have rotated the view so the the cone sticks out the back. If you don't want to see that sticking out the back you could use a clipping path to hide it.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean "You appear to be looking down onto the cone, when the view should be looking _up_ into the cone" instead?

Comment: @Luciano - yes, I made an edit.

Comment: Your answer wasn't quite what I was looking for, but you did help me get the shape of vortex I was looking for. Previously, no matter which way I rotated the vortex, it would always look as though the tip of the cone was on top. But I switched the stroke to color and made the fill no color, and for some reason, that fixed it! Thanks!